# Target class does not exist. Routing Prefix Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I am learning Laravel 9, and I got a problem  `Target class [Admin\DashboardController] does not exist.` when using prefix routing. Is someone can help me to fix it?

this code on routes/web:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/','DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

this code on App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){
        return view('pages.admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've specified an incorrect `namespace` in your `route`. As per the error message:

> Target class [Admin\DashboardController] does not exist

Laravel expects to find a `DashboardController` in the `Admin` `namespace`, however, you've defined your `DashboardController` with the `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin`.

Update the `namespace` on your route.

```
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/','DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#the-default-route-files), you will see that you must use another way:

```php
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
});
```